# MFC C++ LINK 2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall

Tags: c++, mfc, linker

VC2012, I have a solution with many projects.
I have made a "Common" project that contains classes to be used from another projects (for general purpose).
Under "Common" I added a class named

> "PreRequisitesManager" (cpp+h)

and interface

> (PreRequisitesInterface).

On "Client" project (Added as dependency the "Common" project) I have class

> ClientDlg

. the interface was added as needed and added a member of type

> 'PreRequisitesManager'

.

> The ClientDlg.h includes "PreRequisitesManager.h"
>   PreRequisitesManager includes the PreRequisitesInterface.h.

I am getting this:

> GetCVClientDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: __thiscall
>   CPreRequisitesManager::~CPreRequisitesManager(void)"
>   (??1CPreRequisitesManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   __unwindfunclet$??0CGetCVClientDlg@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z$0 GetCVClientDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: __thiscall
>   CPreRequisitesManager::CPreRequisitesManager(void)"
>   (??0CPreRequisitesManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public:
>   __thiscall CGetCVClientDlg::CGetCVClientDlg(class CWnd *)" (??0CGetCVClientDlg@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z) .

Comment: The linker is complaining there is no definition for the destructor and the default constructor of `CPreRequisitesManager`. Are these functions defined in "Common"? Does "Client" link "Common"? And if "Common" is a DLL, are they exported?

Comment: Seems most likely that you forgot to export `CPreRequisitesManager`. Eg, `__declspec(dllexport)`. You'll need some preprocessor defines to determine whether to `dllexport` or `dllimport`. That's been covered on here before if you google it.

Comment: Common is not a DLL. These functions are ONLY in PreRequisitesManager, What do you mean Client link Common ? And there are no class named Common, inside the project Common i only have "CommonDefs.h" for global defintions

Comment: I have made: class __declspec(dllexport) CPreRequisitesManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

the problem was the project was compiled as EXE and not as DLL.

Thanks for help.